# How to update ADF schedule triggers dynamically

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, triggers, azure-data-factory

We have a Adf pipeline it has multiple schedule triggers to kick off.

How to modify these triggers start time dynamically?

So the scenario is,
the start time will be updated by business team in sql server in one of the table and that start time should update in triggers dynamically.

Could anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First use a logic app to execute when a SQL row is updated or inserted ([LINK](https://microsoft.github.io/AzureTipsAndTricks/blog/tip156.html)).

Then as a 2nd step in the work flow, after verifying that you needed to update the trigger, you can trigger the ADF rest API to update a specific trigger ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/triggers/create-or-update?tabs=HTTP#triggers_update)) based on the data in the SQL.